# Number of functions with certain property

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $f : \{1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{1,2,3\}$ be a function. Then the number of functions $g : \{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for at least one $x$ belonging to $\{1,2,3\}$ is what?

My reasoning was that total number of functions $f$ will be $3^3$ and for each of these functions I can have $g$ take exactly the same values as $f$ does so the answer would be $27$ but this answer is not correct, can someone please provide the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the number of functions $\{1,...,n\} \to \{1,...,m\}$ is $m^n$.

Hence the number of functions in this case is $3^3$.

Remember $f$ is one specific function.

It is easier to count the number of $g$s that do **not** equal $f$ anywhere.

In particular, the range of such a $g$ must have size $2$ not $3$, hence the number
of such functions is $2^3$.

Hence the number of the other $g$s, which is what you are looking for, is
$3^3-2^3$.

**Elaboration**: What I mean is that $g(k)$ takes the values $\{1,2,3\} \setminus \{f(k)\}$, and for all $k$ we have $| \{1,2,3\} \setminus \{f(k)\} | = 2$.

Comment: By size do you mean the number of values $g$ takes ???

Comment: @user601297: Yes, excuse my tired wording. The point is at any $x$, we remove the value $f(x)$ from $g$s range. We don't care about the particular value here, just how many remain, which is $2$ for each value of $x$.

Comment: But the example that @Bram28 gave has $g$ take all 3 values.

Comment: In the example $g(1)$ must be one of $2,3$, $f(2)$ must be one of $1,3$ and $g(3)$ must be one of $1,2$. In all cases, the size of the range is $3-1=2$.

Comment: Your answer is definitely correct, I’m just having a hard time understanding this, thanks anyways.

Comment: Ohh, man, I finally got it, great solution, the elaboration helped a lot, thanks man.

Comment: @user601297: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

It is more important to understand why your answer does not work.

Let's say that $f(1)=1, f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$

Then if you have $g(1)=2, g(2)=3$ and $f(3)=1$ (this is one of the $27$ possble functions for $g$), you have no $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$. So, not all $27$ possible functions for $g$ will have at least one 'match' with $f$.

Do you see how you can correct for this?

Comment: I’m sorry but I still don’t get it, why can’t I just change one of the $g$ values to match with $f$?

Comment: @user601297 Yes, you can, but that would be a different $g$: one of the other $26$. So, for some of the $27$ possible $g$'s you get a match, but for others you do not.

Comment: I would really be grateful if you could provide me with the process to come to the right number, I will probably understand it better that way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is easier to count the number $a$ of functions $g$ such that $g(x)\not=f(x)$ *for all $x\in\{1,2,3\}$* first. Then the set of functions you are looking has cardinality $b-a$ where $b$ denotes the number of *all* functions mapping $\{1,2,3\}$ Info itself.